# How to bind multiple input fields including radio button to list in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i have a scenario where i have a questions (stored in database with type e.g text,radio or textarea) which a user can answer Now and i need three types of input fields based on question type e.g if question type is radio i show user a radio button same for question type textarea or text

```
@foreach (Questions question in Model.questions)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <h3>@question.Question</h3>
            @if (question.type == "radio")
            {
                <label>Yes</label>
                <input value="yes" type="@question.type" asp-for="@Model.answers"/>
                <label>No</label>
                <input value="no" type="@question.type" asp-for="@Model.answers" />
            }
            else if (question.type == "textarea")
            {
                <textarea rows="5" cols="40" type="@question.type" asp-for="@Model.answers"></textarea>
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="@question.type" asp-for="@Model.answers" value="" />
            }
        </div>

    }
```

and i want to bind these answers to List

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult review(int id, List<string> answers)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

it work for input type textarea and text but there are two problems with input type radio

1. it wont bind if i did not select one of the option so i used required attribute which solves the first problem
2. now if i have two different questions of type radio and because i am using same name for all i am only able to answer one of them. Now is there any other way of solving this problem?

Comment: You can start this task using indexers.

Answer (score 0):

> This is because you set the same name value for each group of
>   RadioButton, so it will only select the RadioButton value of your last
>   click.

You need to customize different names for RadioButton to ensure that each group of RadioButton can choose a value.

Once the name value is overridden, I suggest that you use ajax to pass the answers to the controller.

Please refer to the code below:

```html
@model WebApplication_core.Models.questionAnswer
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var i = 0;
}
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#submitButton").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                var dataArray = $("form").serializeArray();
                var answers = [];
                $(dataArray).each(function (i, field) {
                    if (i != dataArray.length - 1) {
                        answers.push(field.value);
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $("form").attr('action'),
                    data: { id: 1, answers: answers },//The id value here, because you did not provide it, please get it according to your actual code.
                    success: function (response) {
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            })
        })
    </script>
}
<h1>Test</h1>

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="review">
    @foreach (questions question in Model.questions)
    { 
        <div class="form-group">
            <h3>@question.Question</h3>
            @if (question.type == "radio")
            {
                <label>Yes</label>
                <input value="yes" type="@question.type" asp-for="@Model.answers" name="@Model.answers@i" />
                <label>No</label>
                <input value="no" type="@question.type" asp-for="@Model.answers" name="@Model.answers@i" />
            }
            else if (question.type == "textarea")
            {
                <textarea rows="5" cols="40" type="@question.type" asp-for="@Model.answers"></textarea>
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="@question.type" asp-for="@Model.answers" value="" />
            }
        </div>
        i++;
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitButton" />
</form>
```